# Use HTML in footer iTextShart

Tags: html, itext

I want to use HTML in a footer in iTextShart 5.5.9. I have spent hours finding examples but noting works. I use a IPdfPageEvent OnEndPage to add the footer. This example works but it is not HTML:

```
        public void OnEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
        {
            var phrase = new Phrase("Footer");
            PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;
            ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(cb);
            ct.SetSimpleColumn(phrase, document.Left, document.GetBottom(50), document.Right, document.Bottom, 10, Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
            ct.Go();
        }
```

This sample should be able to handle HTML, works (compiles) but does not show a footer. What am I doing wrong?

```
public void OnEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
        {
            ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(writer.DirectContent);
            XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(new ColumnTextElementHandler(ct), new StringReader("Footer"));
            ct.SetSimpleColumn(document.Left, document.Top, document.Right, document.GetTop(-20), 10, Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE);
            ct.Go();
        }

        private class ColumnTextElementHandler : IElementHandler
        {
            public ColumnTextElementHandler(ColumnText ct)
            {
                _ct = ct;
            }

            private readonly ColumnText _ct;

            public void Add(IWritable w)
            {
                if (w is WritableElement)
                {
                    foreach (IElement e in ((WritableElement)w).Elements())
                    {
                        _ct.AddElement(e);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Did you see the [example on the iText website](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-add-html-headers-and-footers-page)? Just use the simpler `ParseToElementList()` method, you shouldn't need to create a new class for this.

Comment: Yes, I did see the example and tried it but it showed no footer. Since you pointed me to the example I tried again. I found out that the rectangle was to small for my content so it showed nothing.